# How to display Layout of Child Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I have created a `BaseActivity` that just creates a `NavigationDrawer`.

Then i created a `TestActivity` that extends `BaseActivity`.

The `TestActivity` successfully draws the `Drawer` that is added in its Parent Activity.

Now `TestActivity` has some of its own features. I have added a couple of button in it, but its not displaying its own content.

I searched this on net and add these lines in my code, but still its not making any difference.

It displays me blank activity with `header` and `NavigationDrawer`

```
public class TestActivity extends BaseNavigationActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      /*  setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);*/

        ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.base_layout);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_test, content, true);

    }
```

**`BaseActivity` layout XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.tixsee.mavs.HomeActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_main"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/base_layout">

        <include layout="@layout/header_layout"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/sidebg"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        app:itemTextColor= "#ffffff"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
        android:gravity="bottom|left"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        >

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**BaseClassNavigation.Java**

public abstract BaseNavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
static DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
FrameLayout headerLayout;
LinearLayout homeLayout;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
NavigationView navigationView;
Button btnOpenDrawer;
Boolean displayHeader= Boolean.TRUE;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_main);
    headerLayout= (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.header_layout);
    btnOpenDrawer= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_openDrawer);
    homeLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.home_layout);

    btnOpenDrawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
    });


    getNavigationControls();
  }
```

> `GetNavigationControls` contains all the `switch-case`statement to
>   open the requested `Activity` or `fragment`

Kindly guide me how to display child class layout content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your BaseActivity `abstract`

Define an abstract method which gets your layout res from child class.

```
protected abstract int getLayoutRes();
```

In your test activity implement your abstract method `getLayoutRes();`like below

```
@Override
protected int getLayoutRes() {
    return R.id.base_layout;
}
```

In your BaseActivity's `onCreate` method get your child layout inflate it and add to your container like below:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_parent_activity_layout_with_drawer);

        ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.base_layout);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(getLayoutRes(),content,true);

    }
```

With this approach you can add more activities which extends `BaseActivity` just implementing abstract `getLayoutRes()` method in.

Good Luck..

Edit: Here's your BaseActivity code

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

static DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
FrameLayout headerLayout;
LinearLayout homeLayout;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
NavigationView navigationView;
Button btnOpenDrawer;
Boolean displayHeader= Boolean.TRUE;

protected abstract int getLayoutRes();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_main);
    headerLayout= (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.header_layout);
    btnOpenDrawer= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_openDrawer);
    homeLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.home_layout);

    btnOpenDrawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
    });

    getNavigationControls();

    ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.base_layout);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(getLayoutRes(),content,true);

  }
```

}

Comment: Thanks, When i turn my `Baseclass` into Interface, it starts giving me error messages -`Annotations are not allowed here` , `Class or Interface expected`

Comment: do not change into interface. make it abstract. public abstract class BaseActivity

Comment: Thank you so much for the Help :) 
On run time its giving me this error message     `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0d0098 type` Although the resource does exist

Comment: your layout id. for example R.layout.my_awesome_layout

Answer (score 1):

Try using this Code in Oncreate

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
```